# Protocol error 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am calling a web service(.asmx) from my application.When i use the proxy class(service reference) it works fine.If i call the same service with the Web request class i am getting 500 internal server code error .The web exception status is protocol error.I am using asp.net c# to test the web service.

i have sample code for both cases'

with webrequest class

```
            string fileName = @"C:\Departmentpost.xml";

            var req = WebRequest.Create("http://exz.net/webservices/exzwspost.asmx/ProcessDept");


            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "https://www.exz.net/ProcessDept");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
                writer.Close();
            }

            using (var rsp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                var html = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            }

            if (req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
        }
```

The service reference proxy class code

```
Context.Response.ContentType = @"text/xml"; 
string fileName = @"C:\Departmentpost.xml";
XmlDocument docs= new XmlDocument();   
docs.Load(fileName);  
XmlNode node = docs; 
WebservicePostTest.devservice.WSPostSoapClient post = new devservice.WSPostSoapClient("WSPostSoap2");

             XmlNode Xdoc = post.ProcessDept(node);


            XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
            result.AppendChild(result.ImportNode(Xdoc, true));
            Response.Write(result.InnerXml);
            Response.End();
```